# Can I define object's property data type

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, null

I am sending an object to my Web API. Can I define data type of properties of the object, otherwise everything is string.

```
let object: any = {};
object.Date = this.Expense.Date;
object.Description = this.Expense.Description;
object.Rate=this.Expense.Rate;
```

because if I send nothing for Rate then it give me error that cannot convert null to decimal. I want to send Rate as decimal and with null value. In web API, its data type is decimal and that is not required parameter.

Comment: `object.Rate = this.Expense.Rate || 0`…?

Comment: If you want to store each type, could you just nest it in the property during transit? (like: `object.Rate.type = "decimal", object.Rate.value = this.Expense.Rate;`) Of course you'd have to "unpack" it at the  other end, which only works if you're in control of the API.

Comment: I have Control over Web API  I am using following code . I am using   
    public void Post([FromBody] Expense expense)
    { command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rate", (Decimal)expense.Rate);

Comment: I am getting this error          Cannot set property 'type' of undefined by using  object.Rate.type="decimal"

Comment: Are you sure that the type of the variable `object` is actually `any` in your code? (otherwise, please show use the relevant part of the type/interface definition) Is the last line of the code you showed us the place where the error happens? It's a compilation error, correct?

Comment: Could you try to define `object.Rate` only if it not null? Either `if (this.Expense.Rate != null) object.Rate=this.Expense.Rate;` or maybe `this.Expense.Rate == null ? undefined : this.Expense.Rate;`